# What is causing the error "Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator" in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

Here's what I have so far.

```js
'use strict';

const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi")

const server = new Hapi.Server({ host: "0.0.0.0", port: 80 });

server.route({
    method: "POST",
    path: "/board",
    options: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                name: Joi.object({
                    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(15)
                })
            }
        }
    },
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        // do stuff
    }
});

server.start();
```

This produces the error

```
Error: Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator
    at new module.exports (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\error.js:23:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as assert] (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\assert.js:20:11)
    at Object.exports.compile (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\validation.js:48:10)
    at module.exports.internals.Route._setupValidation (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\route.js:197:43)
    at new module.exports.internals.Route (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\route.js:122:14)
    at internals.Server._addRoute (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:498:23)
    at internals.Server.route (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:491:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Fukatsumu\Desktop\projects\Textboard\index.js:37:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I expected this to validate the request, but instead it's producing an error message that there are very few details on how to fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi")

const server = new Hapi.Server({ host: "0.0.0.0", port: 80 });

server.route({
    method: "POST",
    path: "/board",
    options: {
        validate: {
            payload: Joi.object({
                    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(15)
                })
        }
    },
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        // do stuff
    }
});

server.start();
```

> payload: Joi.object({
>                           name: Joi.string().min(1).max(15)
>                       })

Comment: I had all of my routes broken out in separate files, so I was confused as to why I was getting this exception at the `server.route` method call (it wasn't obvious). This explained it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[On upgrading to Latest hapi](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4017), check your code for route validate and response.schema settings and if you are passing values that must be compiled (see above for the lack of Joi.object() as a typical case), either wrap your schema with **`Joi.object()`** or call **`server.validator(Joi)`**

Comment: This server.validator() option requires no structural changes and therefore imho should be the choice of preference.  Thanks @tk120404!